# Integrate and derivative

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

i'm not able to explain the following step:

$\frac{1}{k+v(x)}=\frac{d^2 v}{dx^2}$
by integrating this equation:

$(C-\frac{1}{k+v(x)})^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{dv}{dx}$

Please, if somebody can help i'll be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $v'dx=dv$, you have
$$\frac{dv}{k+v}=v'dv'.$$
Integrating,
$$\ln(k+v)+C=\frac12v'^2,$$and
$$(2\ln(k+v)+C)^{1/2}=\frac{dv}{dx}.$$
Not the expected answer.

Likely fix:
$$\frac{dv}{(k+v)^\color{red}2}=\color{red}2v'dv',$$
$$C-\frac1{k+v}=v'^2,$$
$$(C-\frac1{k+v})^{1/2}=\frac{dv}{dx}.$$